# Как правильно ставить ударение в фамилии Джигурда?

Tags: орфоэпия

Никита Джигурда. Подскажите. А то у меня спор с подругой. Она считает, что правильно на букве "и" ударение, а я всегда думала, что на букве "у"))

Answer (score 3):

Правильно - на последнем слоге: важно, как конкретный носитель фамилии определяет ударение.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно в данном случае - Джигурда́